# adding natwidth and natheight to \photo in moderncv

Tags: graphics, moderncv

I am using winEdt 6 with MikTex 2.9 and writing a resume with moderncv package.
The problem is I can't make the cv title because it cannot determine the size of the photo.
I want a way to put the size of the .jpg picture.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith} 
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\phone{(000) 111 1112}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@smith.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/picture.jpg} 
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: your code work well for me. what error do you have

Comment: the error is in \photo "cannot determin size of graphics (no bounding box)"
This generates an error in makecvtitle because the photo is not rendered

Comment: Are you compiling with `latex` ?. If so, compile with `pdflatex`. `latex` can't take `.jpg` files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.